# .htaccess file with an iOS enterprise app

Tags: ios, .htaccess, password-protection, in-house-distribution

I've setup an iOS enterprise app distribution for internal use and protected it via .htaccess file.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile http://domain.com/path/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

and an index.html file

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://domain.com/path/enterprise_viewer.plist">
```

But the problem is, it asks for the password 3 times whenever user opens the index.html in their browser, once for the access, and second and third time after clicking the download link.

Any suggestions to reduce password prompts to 1.

Answer (score 0):

After the access, the subsequent request aren't made through browser, and this is the reason why you should authenticate again.

We've solved it protecting only the .ipa file in this way:

```
<Files *.ipa>
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile http://domain.com/path/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
</Files>
```